# Columns with a Right Parenthesis

Tags: multicolumn, columns, brackets, frame

I want to arrange my frame as shown in the attached figure. However, despite the idea, I don't know how to do that. Please help me out.

The left and right columns need not be framed. I used frames here for a better understanding of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which solution to choose heavily depends on the context in which you wish to use such an arrangement. Since this was not clear to me, I opted for a very customizable variant using the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{twocolbox}[1]{
    empty,
    left*=0pt,
    right*=25pt,
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top,
    sidebyside gap=15pt,
    overlay={
        \draw[decorate, decoration={brace}] 
            ([xshift=-15pt, yshift=-10pt]frame.north east) -- 
            ([xshift=-15pt, yshift=10pt]frame.south east) 
            node[midway, xshift=10pt, rotate=-90, font=\large] {#1};
    }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{twocolbox}{Methods}

Random Text in Left Column

\lipsum[1]

\tcblower

Random Text in Right Column

\lipsum[2]

\end{twocolbox}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Since you can use the full scope of Ti*k*Z magic here, it is easy to color the brace or draw it thicker or make it look more like the braces in math mode (for this you also need to load the `calligraphy` library):

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}

% [...]

\newtcolorbox{twocolbox}[1]{
    empty,
    left*=0pt,
    right*=25pt,
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top,
    sidebyside gap=15pt,
    overlay={
        \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace}, pen colour={blue}, very thick] 
            ([xshift=-15pt, yshift=-10pt]frame.north east) -- 
            ([xshift=-15pt, yshift=10pt]frame.south east) 
            node[midway, xshift=10pt, rotate=-90, font=\large] {#1};
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to colour the right brace and increase its thickness? and Thank you @Jasper Habicht

Comment: @user84456 Yes. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that uses side by side `minipage` environments. The first (outer) minipage contains a second pair of side by side "inner" minipages, which contain the itemized lists. The second outer minipage serves to house the rotated string "Methods".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable class
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro
\usepackage{enumitem} % for \newlist and \setlist macros
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1} % create a bespoke itemize-like list env.
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label=\textbullet,left=0pt,nosep,
            before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRight},
            after={\strut\end{minipage}}}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox macro
\usepackage{lipsum}   % filler text

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\begin{center}
$\left.
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}     % outer minipage (choose a suitable width)
%% sum of widths of two "inner" minipages and of \hspace instr. should equal `1\linewidth`. 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}  % first inner minipage
\begin{myitemize}
\item \lipsum[2][1-3] % filler text
\item \lipsum[3][1-3] % more filler text
\end{myitemize}
\end{minipage}%                     % end of first inner minipage
\hspace{0.05\linewidth}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth} % second inner minipage
\begin{myitemize}
\item \lipsum[3][1-3]
\item \lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{myitemize}
\end{minipage}%                     % end of second inner minipage
\end{minipage}                      % end of outer minipage
\hspace{1em}
\right\}$
\hspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}{0.04\textwidth}    % encase \rotatebox instruction in another minipage
\rotatebox{-90}{\huge Methods}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your own environment, in order not to pollute the document with raw code. Choose a better name than `foo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newlength{\foowidth}
\newlength{\foowidthaux}
\newenvironment{foo}[1]
 {%
  \begin{flushleft}
  \sbox{\foobox}{\rotatebox[origin=Bc]{-90}{\LARGE#1}}%
  \settowidth{\foowidthaux}{%
    $\Biggr\rbrace\,\usebox{\foobox}$%
    \hspace{2\arraycolsep}%
  }%
  \setlength{\foowidth}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\foowidthaux)/2\relax}%
  $\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\foowidth}
 }
 {%
  \end{minipage}
  \end{array}
  \right\rbrace\!\usebox{\foobox}$
  \end{flushleft}
 }
\newcommand{\changecolumn}{\end{minipage}&\begin{minipage}[t]{\foowidth}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{foo}{Methods}
\lipsum[3][1-6]
\changecolumn
\lipsum[4]
\end{foo}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I save the part to be rotated, so I can measure it, together with a couple of adjustments, so I can compute the width for the two minipages. They are top aligned inside an `array`, so `\right\rbrace` can do the right thing and cover the whole thing, independent of the text in the two minipages.

The `\changecolumn` command provides the end for the left minipage, the alignment character and the begin for the right minipage.